# Head start with wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

Am having a bit of challenge in laying out my form using sizers in wxPython, i would appreciate if someone would give me head start in laying out my form as shown in the image.

[image: Sample Form]

Please share the sources.

Thanks

Comment: what tool did you use to create the mockup ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not mess with sizers manually when designing a complex gui. Just, please, use [wxglade](https://bitbucket.org/agriggio/wxglade) and customize manually afterwards.

It took 15 minutes to do this, mistakes included (I did not filled the list control, sorry):

[image]

This is the process I followed:

```
1) Add a Frame widget, select a wx.Frame.  

2) Customize wx.Frame properties:  
     Give the Frame a MenuBar (the property dialog for the menubar appears).  
     Customize MenuBar: Add File, Edit...  
     Go back to the Frame properties' View (click the Frame icon on the wxglade Tree View).  
     (not nice but it's the way I found to go in and out from Menu and StatusBar dialogs).  
     Give the wx.Frame a StatusBar. Go back (click the Frame icon in the wxglade Tree View).  

3) Create 3 vertical slots from the default BoxSizer (right-click on the sizer + add * 3)
      1st slot: 
          Add a BoxSizer with 5 horizontal slots
          Set proportion=0 to the sizer, set border=5 and mark wxALL
          Add 4 Buttons and a Spacer in those slots
          Mark EXPAND and set proportion=1 in the Spacer properties.

      2nd slot:
          Add a SplitterWindow. Select Vertical type.
          Optionally set border=5 with wxALL
          Add a BoxSizer to each section of the SplitterWindow
          At its left, add a ListCtrl
          At its right, add a NoteBook
          Customize NoteBook:
              Add 4 sheets.
              Add BoxSizer with 2 vertical slots to first notebook sheet.
                  1st slot: insert a wx.Panel.
                  2nd slot: add a BoxSizer with 3 horizontal slots.
                      Set proportion=0 to the sizer.
                      Add 2 buttons and 1 Spacer in those slots.
                      Mark EXPAND and set proportion=1 in the Spacer properties.

      3rd slot:
          Add a BoxSizer with 5 horizontal slots.
          Set proportion=0 to the sizer, set border=5 with wxALL
          Add 2 Buttons, 1 Spacer and 2 Buttons more.
          Mark EXPAND and set proportion=1 in the Spacer properties.

4) Give background colour to the Frame.
  (Choose wisely, you still have 5 minutes left of the 15 allotted).
```

And finally, customize labels, sizer and widget names, etc.
Save the wxGlade file for future changes and produce the Python file (In the top Application dialog).
***Trick:*** Do not modify the generated file, instead import and subclass your Frame in another file to code its functionality.

***One last note:*** In my experience there are some differences in Linux and Windows with sizers and backgrounds. In Linux, do not use the default Frame's BoxSizer as indicated in step 3. Instead add an wx.Panel on it, add a BoxSizer to the Panel and continue building from this sizer.

Comment: Great!! Thanks I tried wrapping my head around wxGlade, gave me hell, this site did the trick for me http://wiki.wxpython.org/BoxSizerFromTheGroundUp   Its funny am finding it easy to draw the form manually rather than using a designer. if you did in 15mins, i'll give it another shot.

Comment: @gath, once you have your frame view, you just need to follow a sequence: insert sizer with n slots and then for each slot, either fill slot with widget and customize it or add another sizer (and recurse here). Thanks for the link, it's new for me. Did you also checked the tutorial and docs included in the wxglade package ? The tool is relatively simple but really powerful at the same time (or because that). Once you get used to the tricks for customization the major problem, the one taking more time to you, building complex GUI's is to select the combination of colours.

Comment: Thanks lots! followed your instructions, and i agree, its kinda faster to produce complex gui using glade! Thanks. Btw, have you ever installed wxWidgets/wxPython on a linux box? my attempt was sheer pain!!

Comment: I have it on all my PC's with ubuntu. Not sure if it was there by default or if I used ubuntu software manager to get it from the ubuntu official repository, but for sure I had no problem with it. You don't need to use any manual linux console install instruction. I would remember it otherwise. I just checked and for Ubuntu 11.4
(natty), ubuntu repositories provides wxpython 2.8.12.0.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the heck of it, I decided to see how long it would take me to hand code something similar. It took my around 35 minutes or so. And I skipped the menubar. Oh well. Here's the code anyway:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class TabPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        btnOne = wx.Button(self, label="button_10")
        btnTwo = wx.Button(self, label="button_11")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(btnOne, 0, wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM)
        sizer.Add(btnTwo, 0, wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class LeftPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self, size=(-1,100),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Subject')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Due')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Location', width=125)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class RightPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        notebook = wx.Notebook(self)
        page1 = TabPanel(notebook)
        page2 = TabPanel(notebook)
        page3 = TabPanel(notebook)

        notebook.AddPage(page1, "Page_1")
        notebook.AddPage(page2, "Page_2")
        notebook.AddPage(page3, "Page_3")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # create row of buttons
        for i in range(4):
            btn = wx.Button(self, label="button_%s" % i)
            btnSizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(btnSizer)

        # create splitter
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        leftPanel = LeftPanel(splitter)
        rightPanel = RightPanel(splitter)
        splitter.SplitVertically(leftPanel, rightPanel)
        mainSizer.Add(splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        # add second row of buttons
        btnSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        btn5 = wx.Button(self, label="button_5")
        btn6 = wx.Button(self, label="button_6")
        btn7 = wx.Button(self, label="button_7")
        btn8 = wx.Button(self, label="button_8")
        btnSizer2.Add(btn5)
        btnSizer2.Add(btn6)
        btnSizer2.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        btnSizer2.Add(btn7)
        btnSizer2.Add(btn8)
        mainSizer.Add(btnSizer2)

        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Sample", size=(600,800))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        statusbar.SetStatusText("Test")
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Great!. There are some more things you win with wxglade visual design and automatic code generation: 1) The code generated is more flat, all the GUI is in one class. This makes widgets directly accessible from subclasses without cumbersome levels of inheritance. This seems against code structure, code reuse, etc. But I thing this is not important here because if you want to reuse some complex panel from a gui it is faster to copy/paste the widget between two opened wxglade design views (I have done that and it rocks !) or to redesign your gui in the design view and generate a new gui class.

Comment: 2) It never forgets to set style, self or ID: It works at first try. 3) The code sturdines also helps further coding such as binding widget events to functions, changing some properties dinamically from main class (you need some self's for that, Mike), etc

Comment: I didn't make all the widgets into properties because I didn't need to. Most of the time, you don't need to make buttons into class properties anyway. Yes, having everything in one class is handy, but I find it messy. I didn't think I was using any cumbersome inheritance here, but to each their own. One thing the OP can learn is that everyone has their own coding style. I used to put everything into one class, but now I try not to because I like to reuse my code and it's easier to tweak sizers in their own classes, at least in my mind.